# Puzzling out how a simple python 2.7 program works

Tags: python

I'm super new to this and I'm trying to puzzle my way through is code and I'm stuck, I don't know how the program is referencing the lists I've copied/created. At the end it makes a new list called 'words'. I don't understand how 'words' is getting my previous lists inside of it.

```
'''
Making silly Sentences Game
'''
name = ['Bob', 'Rachel', 'Don']
verb = ['slaps', 'steals', 'jumps over']
noun = ['jello', 'car', 'U-571']

from random import randint 

def pick (words):
    num_words = len(words)

    num_picked = randint(0, num_words -1)

    word_picked = words[num_picked] **#THIS BIT HERE!!! How does it know what 'words' is?**

    return word_picked

print (pick(name),pick(verb), 'a', pick(noun))
```

This is my first post so, I'm almost certain it's in the wrong place. Please be gentle.

Comment: unrelated: `print(random.choice(name), random.choice(verb), 'a', random.choice(noun))` achieves the same goal without re-inventing the wheel. Also, `random.randrange(num_words)` is better than `randint(0, num_words -1)`

Comment: I recommend to study python more deeply before needlessly banging your head against simple and obvious traits/pitfalls of the language. Learn about namespaces, scope, objects, classes, etc. Try with [Learning Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do)

Comment: This is literally week 1 of my trying to learn python. I am still getting myself into trouble with a lot of what I'm writing.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with scope.
The line `word_picked = words[num_picked]` can "see" `words` because it is in the scope of the function `pick()`, which takes a single arguments `words`. So when you call `pick(name)`, within the scope of `pick()`, `words` is now pointing to `name`.

Answer (score 1):

It knows what `words` is because you told it.

When you did `def pick(words)` you defined a function which takes one argument, `words`. This means that whatever you pass as that argument will be available as `words` inside the function.

Now, when you called `pick(name)`, you passed in the value `name` as the argument. So the value that was known as `name` is passed into the function, which receives it as `words`.